# Trouble solving two number theoretical problems

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Suppose $k\in\mathbb N$ and suppose $2^k+1=u^2$ and $2^k-1=v^2$ for some $u,v\in\mathbb N$. I have to prove that the first case implies $k=3$ and the second case implies $k=1$. Also, for the second case it is hinted to use the fact (lemma) that if $n$ is odd, then $n^2\equiv1 \pmod 8$, but I suppose it could be used for the first one as well. My progress so far:

> First question:
>
> Suppose $u$ is even, then $u=2t$ for some $t\in\mathbb N$, thus $u^2=4t^2=2^k+1$. Notice that two divides the left hand side of the equation, therefore it also divides the right hand side. Since it divides $2^k$ for any $k\ge1$, it must also divide $1$, contradiction. So $u$ is odd and therefore $u^2\equiv1\pmod 8$. Thus there exists an $m\in\mathbb Z$ such that $u^2=8m+1=2^k +1$. Thus $2^k=8m$, therefore $k\ge3$.

I am stuck at this point, however. I suppose setting $k>3$ and finding a contradiction would be a possible method, but I do not know what $k>3$ actually has to offer to solve this problem. No other method I think of gets me anywhere, either. I guess I could try to show that $2^k+1$ cannot be a square for $k>3$. Perhaps I could use the fact that $u^2-2^k=1$ or that $\gcd(u^2,2^k)=1$.

> Second question:
>
> The same reasoning can be applied to show that $v$ has to be even. Therefore, according to the lemma proposed above, $2^k-1=v^2\equiv1\pmod 8$. This implies $2^k\equiv2\pmod 8$. For any $k\ge3$ there exists some $t\in \mathbb N$ such that $2^k=8t$, therefore $2^k\equiv0\pmod 8$, which leads to a contradiction. Checking for $k=1,2$ leads to the conclusion that $k=1$ is the only possibility.

I think I have actually figured out this proof while writing down the progress I already have made, but for the sake of completeness and to check it's correctness I will leave it here.

Comment: What you wrote looks right to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us continue with your first case. As you proved, $k\geq 3$ and $u$ is odd, so $u=2x+1$ for some $x$. This implies $2^k=4x^2+4x$, that is $2^{k-2}=x(x+1)$. But then, either $x$ or $x+1$ is odd, and the only odd number that divides a power of $2$ is $1$.

Comment: I see, very nice and simple continuation to my proof. From $x=1$, it follows that $u=3$, thus $2^k+1=9$, which implies $k=3$.

Comment: Also, $x=0$ cannot occur, since that would imply $2^k=0$, which is clearly not solvable in $\mathbb N$.

Comment: I must admit I forgot about the case $x=0$. The end of the solution is as you say, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If $u^2-1=(u+1)(u-1)=2^k$, both $u+1$ and $u-1$ are powers of $2$. The only powers of $2$ that differ by two units are $2^1$ and $2^2$, hence $u^2=2^3+1$.

If $v^2+1=2^k$, $v$ is odd, let $2w+1$, and $4w^2+4w+2=2(2w^2+2w+1)=2^k$. The only power of $2$ that is odd is $2^0$, hence $v^2=2\cdot 2^0-1$.

Comment: Thank you for presenting me with this alternative approach. I find it very helpfull to see a different solution than the one I had in mind, especially if it is this straightforward!